# How to create makefile for all 3 C files?

Tags: c, makefile, shared-memory

Extreme beginner at using Makefile. I looked at other questions, but they all seem very complicated. I want to compile all 3 .c files by using a Makefile. They are SwimMill.c, Fish.c, and Pellets.c.

```
all: SwimMill Fish Pellets

SwimMill: SwimMill.c
    gcc -o SwimMill SwimMill.c

Fish: Fish.c
    gcc -o Fish Fish.c -lm

Pellets: Pellets.c
    gcc -o Pellets Pellets.c
```

After that, what do I type in the command line to compile the Makefile? Is it make -f Makefile?

Comment: that looks okay, except that you should add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to make sure you're not overlooking compiler warnings. and your makefile isn't aware of possible .h (header) files

Comment: Just `make` will run the first target in the Makefile, so in your case `make all`.  There is no need per se to educate Make about how to compile an object file from a C file; it already knows. So this could be reduced to just `all: SwimMill Fish Pellets`

Comment: ... oh except the `-lm` for `Fish` probably needs to be explicit.

Comment: I get this error when I run the makefile: make: *** No rule to make target 'Fish.c', needed by 'Fish'.  Stop.

Comment: You get that error because `Fish.c` is not in the directory where you run `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the format of my Makefiles for **C** programs :

```Makefile
## Variables

SRC = file1.c,
      file2.c,
      file3.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

CFLAGS = -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror

CPPFLAGS = -ImyIncludeFolder

NAME = my_program

## Functions

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    rm -r $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

It's probably not the best Makefile in the world -I mean, definitely not-, but it does the job.
I'm open to any *constructive* critiscism !

### How it works :

I won't insult your intelligence by telling you how variables work.
I'm just explaining implicit rules and variables (as far as I know them).

The `$(OBJ)` implicit rule creates `.o` files.
The `$(CC)` implicit variable is the **C** Compiler (here it might be `gcc`)

The `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` variables are called automatically by the compiler.

- `CFLAGS` contains compiler options (debug level, verbose, and so on...)
- `CPPFLAGS` stands for `C PreProcessor Flags` and defines linking files like the headers.

Hope this helps you understanding and making powerful Makefiles !

Comment: You explained the obvious but what `$(SRC:.c=.o)` means is unclear. Even I never saw that before, what does it even expand into and what is that operator called?

Comment: @PurpleIce It's all [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

Comment: "Substitution reference" would have been enough, cheers.

Although this way it won't compile because there's no rule to compile .o files, so this doesn't really answer the question, unless we assume the asker knows how to use makefile, in which case they would have never asked.

Comment: There is a rule to compile `.o` files, it's implicit with `$(NAME): $(OBJ)`.
The `$(SRC:.c=.o)` just means you take `SRC` and you replace `.c` with `.o`